# Besides using formal derivatives, how can you show that every irreducible polynomial is separable?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

I have recently read a proof that every monic irreducible polynomial over a field of characteristic 0 has no repeated roots. The proof uses derivatives. The last time I encountered a proof of this statement, it required derivatives as well. Is there another way to prove this without using derivatives? It seems a bit out of place (calculus in algebra?) and I was wondering if there was another proof that did not employ derivatives.

Thanks!

Comment: It's not a real derivative, it's a [formal derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_derivative), which is a completely algebraic calculation that doesn't involve limits and is only used for polynomials.

Comment: Ah yes...you are right. It just feels weird to me.

Comment: Actually one could argue that derivatives are in some sense necessary for this proof, since it doesn't work in characteristic $p$: so there has to be some indices coming from somewhere, and in a sense they have to come from derivating the polynomial

Comment: After all, we can explicitly evaluate derivatives of polynomials and other elementary functions `by algebra', not be truly looking at some infinite process of limit-taking. That is, some of the best and most useful parts of calculus are exactly those parts that are algebraic.

Comment: Right, right. Thank you Dr. Garrett

Comment: There is an algebraic definition for the formal derivative that does not invoke the power rule at all: the polynomial $f(x)-f(y)\in K[x,y]$ when evaluated at $y=x$ (which is a map $K[x][y]\to K[x]$) yields $0$, therefore $f(x)-f(y)$ is divisible by $(x-y)$ within $K[x,y]$. The quotient $(f(x)-f(y))/(x-y)$ evaluated at $y=x$ yields the derivative $f'(x)\in K[x]$.